# Class design question for Reports in my .NET application that use a conglomeration of Data

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, oop, architecture

Hopefully I can articulate my question well enough to get some clear and usable feedback here. I have reports (like paper reports) in my .NET application that have data bound to them. Typically the reports are a combination of many data elements across several busniess entites that may not all relate through an Inheritance hierarcy, etc. This makes it difficult to get all the needed data placed together to bind to the report.

So what I *have* done before are make 'Report' classes with data elements specific to supporting the reports they are bound to, and on the back end might be tied to specially created Stored Procedures that bring this data back (maybe several joins across many tables to get the *right* data needed). So if I was to make an analogy to the database world, I am essentially 'denormailizing' the data structure to get all of this data into a single class to make it easy to bind to the report.

However on the hard line OOP concepts and architecture design, one could say that a report is just another 'thing' to bind data to, and its class should not be designed just to suit the needs of data binding. In this thought process, I would actually need to make my class design be able to create the relationships needed to get all of the data together properly to still be bound, but not create any *special* 'Report' classes. I find this difficult to do sometimes. It is much easier to create these relationships in the back end stored procedures and then just output the resultset to be almost immediately bound to the report.

So what is the *right* way to solve this? If I create these specialized report classes with really no behavior, am I introducing an anti-pattern like the Anemic Domain Model?

I could use some feedback, and please speak up if my question and scenarios did not make sense. Thanks!

Comment: The language that you are using might be helpful in order to make a good suggestion here. My first thought is to have your classes, or entities support support some sort of common interface for querying the data you desire from them, but I'm not sure that this is good design either. I think that having your reports obtain their data in the most expected (direct) way possible is good practice, Classes should not duplicate the functionality of another class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with having your domain model (simply - data used in your business logic) shaped differently than the data in your database. In other words, you don't have to have one to one correlations.

With this in mind, there is nothing inherently wrong with creating report objects that act like property bags of data sets to render different parts of a report. In fact, since the reports are read only, it is often preferable.

Now, you can set things up so the business logics are more aligned with the database rows and create a view model for the report. This may, or may not, lead to greater reusability. Determination of where to create the shapes that the report binds to is largely dependent on whether or not the datasets make sense as bits you can consume for some business function. If they are truly related to the report only, then consider creating the report classes once and passing them through the business tier.

Hope this makes sense, as I don't think it was my best answer post lately. ;-)

Comment: I think that was pretty clear, thanks for the feedback. You are saying it is OK to have classes in your opinion that just map to reports and have no other major reusability, correct? In projects where I am doing DDD and have an AppServices layer where ViewModels are created, this might work to create a ViewModel to merge data together. However in a simple 3-layer (UI-BLL-DAL) app, I may just have report classes that end up as strongly type List (Of <T>) collections that are bound to the report. Isn't creating these dummy classes with no behavior not a good idea though, or still OK?

Comment: Basically, if you can reuse the bits, then you have to think through the classes a bit more. If all of the classes are report only, tailor what you need for the output.

Comment: BTW, EF is good for making these types of data shapes, as it allows a lot of drag and drop. Even DataSets are good, although a bit dated these days.

Comment: So since each report really only needs (1) method to generate its report in this manner (i.e. RunMyCustomReport() ) would I just use a single class for all reports? My question here is that the single class will have to contain *all* of the properties for *all* of the reports. But if I make a single class for each report, it seems like overkill too because I will only need a single method to generate the report. There really will be no scaling of the class. So which to do: 1 class, several 'GenerateReport' methods will all properties for all reports, or multiple classes, 1 per report?

Comment: If you are going for reuse, then taking time to actually make a domain model (of classes) is your best bet. Classes can be used across "models" in EF, or you can combine them yourself, if you would much rather go that direction. But, I would refactor to reuse, rather than design that way, unless you know a class is used over multiple reports.

Comment: As a follow-up to this older question I asked, another idea is to use a ViewModel class for assembling reporting data as reports are as I mentioned an aggregate of data in a specialized view really. It's just a 'report' control being bound to instead of some other control.